# ldap.OPT_X_TLS_CACERTDIR is not working with certificate file in the directory

Tags: python, ldap, python-ldap

My certificate is present in /etc/certs/mycer.pem file and I am able to authenticate with ldap using code below:

```
import ldap
import os
ldap.set_option(ldap.OPT_X_TLS_REQUIRE_CERT, ldap.OPT_X_TLS_DEMAND)
ls = ldap.initialize('ldaps://<ip>:10636')
ls.set_option(ldap.OPT_REFERRALS, 0)
ls.set_option(ldap.OPT_PROTOCOL_VERSION, 3)
ls.set_option(ldap.OPT_X_TLS_CACERTFILE, "/etc/certs/mycer.pem")                # line 7
ls.set_option(ldap.OPT_X_TLS_NEWCTX, 0)
ls.simple_bind_s('uid=admin,ou=system', 'secret')
```

But if I change `OPT_X_TLS_CACERTFILE` to `OPT_X_TLS_CACERTDIR` in line 7 as:

```
ls.set_option(ldap.OPT_X_TLS_CACERTDIR, "/etc/certs/")
```

Code is not able to authenticate and throws error

```
>>> ls.simple_bind_s('uid=admin,ou=system', 'secret')
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/ldap/ldapobject.py", line 445, in simple_bind_s
    msgid = self.simple_bind(who,cred,serverctrls,clientctrls)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/ldap/ldapobject.py", line 439, in simple_bind
    return self._ldap_call(self._l.simple_bind,who,cred,RequestControlTuples(serverctrls),RequestControlTuples(clientctrls))
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/ldap/ldapobject.py", line 331, in _ldap_call
    reraise(exc_type, exc_value, exc_traceback)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/ldap/compat.py", line 44, in reraise
    raise exc_value
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/ldap/ldapobject.py", line 315, in _ldap_call
    result = func(*args,**kwargs)
ldap.SERVER_DOWN: {'desc': "Can't contact LDAP server", 'info': '(unknown error code)'}
```

There is only one file in the directory. How can python-ldap  use multiple certificate files if this is not the correct way.

Answer (score 1):

As I understand it, python will use OpenSSL and it subsequently scans the `OPT_X_TLS_CACERTDIR` directory for certificate files named `*.crt`.

But I cannot for the life of me find the source of that wisdom.

**Edit:**

I found an old script of mine that contains *both*:

```
conn.set_option(ldap.OPT_X_TLS_CACERTFILE, "")
conn.set_option(ldap.OPT_X_TLS_CACERTDIR, "/etc/ssl/cacerts")
```

Could it be that this empty `OPT_X_TLS_CACERTFILE` setting is somehow required?